# Vagrant ssh: Software caused connection abort

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I'm trying to login to **vargant** on my Windows 7, using this command from my Git Bash:

```
vagrant ssh
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort
```

What software did cause this problem? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was silly.

I just needed to enable **Virtualization** in **BIOS**.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/ssh.html 
This is from the vagrant website, there should be an explanation there for windows users. Good luck hope this helps.